# Setting conditional(ifelse) arguments in a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a simple function and one of its arguments needs to be made conditional, in the sense:

IFELSE NOT MISSING take the given value 
       IFELSE NOT EXISTS then give some default value
              ELSE give the global value of that argument

something like this:

```
f <- function(x,y=ifelse(!missing("y"),y,ifelse(!exists("y"),1,get("y",envir=.GlobalEnv))))
{ 
  assign("y",y,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(x+y)
}
```

required outputs:

```
#    :f(3) should give me 4 with global y=1
#    :f(4,2) should give me 6 with global y=2
#    :f(5) should give me 7 with global y=2
#Note that y does not exist when we first run the function
```

running the above function with f(3) gives me:- Error in get("y", envir = .GlobalEnv) : object 'y' not found

If i specify `y` in the first-go then the function works perfectly, but I want it to run even if the user doesnt specify the `y` argument in the first-go

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT:
@Richard i dont think it matters if missing() is in the function or in the argument, in any case try to do the same using this function:

```
f <- function(x,y)
{ 
  y=ifelse(!missing("y"),y,ifelse(!exists("y"),1,get("y",envir=.GlobalEnv)))
  assign("y",y,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(x+y)
}
```

Comment: Got where i was going wrong..i was checking for the existence of y inside the function as well as global `exists("y")` inherits=T by default.So why this was failing? Ans: ifelse evaluates both yes and no condition if the condition is not always TRUE or FALSE; so when y was missing and undefined anywhere, the second ifelse `!exists("y")` is TRUE and it gave y=1 and then `!exists("y")` became FALSE(as y it did exists inside the function) and it evaluated `get("y", envir = .GlobalEnv)` which gave the error as y didnt exist in the global environment.

Comment: So modifying `exists("y")` to `exists("y",envir=.GlobalEnv)` did the trick. Thanks to Richard, this ifelse concept clicked me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll begin by stating that I don't recommend you do this. You'll be messing around with reassignment of global objects, which can be dangerous and lead to trouble if you need to go back and recall a value that you've overwritten.

Next, `missing` should not be used in the argument list of a function.  It should be used in the function body to check the arguments in the argument list, and has specific usage that is noted in the help file.

That said, if you must do it, here you go.

```
f <- function(x, y)
{
    if(missing(y)) {
        y <- if(exists("y", envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
            get("y", envir = .GlobalEnv)
        } else {
            1L
        }
    }
    assign("y", y, .GlobalEnv)
    x + y
}

> rm(y)
> f(3)
#[1] 4
> f(4, 2)
#[1] 6
> f(5)
#[1] 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
f <- function(x,y=NULL)
{ 
    y = ifelse( !is.null(y),  y,
        ifelse(!exists("y"), 1,get("y",envir=.GlobalEnv)
        )
    )

  assign("y",y,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(x+y)
}
```

If y does not exist, try:

```
f <- function(x,y)
{ 
  if(missing("y") || !exists('y'))  y = 1
  assign("y",y,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  x+y
}
```

Comment: @mso `f(3)#Error in get("y", envir = .GlobalEnv) : object 'y' not found`

Comment: this function is too getting the same error as mentioned above with: f(3). Make sure you remove object y from your workspace before running it. The objective is for it to take a default value if y is missing and it doesnt even exist. => f(3) should give 4 #3+1

Comment: your second function too doesnt work as required. look at my required outputs in the question. anyways richard got it.