# How can I set a conditional function argument value here?

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I want to automatically set the value of an argument in a function based on another argument's value.

More specifically, I want to set a timezone value (`offset`) to automatically adjust time values given the `region`.

However, my implementation doesn't seem to work (as in the offset is never applied unless I specifically pass it as an argument to the function).

Part of the function (is supposed to) set the `offset` value based on `region`'s value, and also connect to the corresponding Elasticsearch server.

This is what I have:

```
if (region == "EU") {
    offset = "+00:00:00"
    # Code to connect to EU ElasticSearch server
  } else if (region == "US") {
    offset = "-06:00:00"
    # Code to connect to US ElasticSearch server
  } else {
  paste0(stop("Incorrect region supplied: ", region))
}
```

The function:

```
time_function <- function(region, retailer, start_date, end_date, offset = "+00:00:00"){
    # Function body
}
```

(Note that I have set the default value of `offset` to `"+00"`, otherwise it will throw an error that the argument is missing.)

Clearly I have gone wrong somewhere because the offset is never applied unless I explicitly specify in the argument list.

This is what I want to do:

If `region == "US"`, then set `offset` to `"-06:00:00"`,
Else if `region == "EU"`, then set `offset` to `"+00:00:00"`
Else `Error message: "supply valid region"`

In short, I am looking to set a conditional argument value.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this related to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884011/setting-conditionalifelse-arguments-in-a-function

Comment: Just a thought: you can't (to my knowledge) have multiple time zones in a single column of a `data.frame.`. Can you provide some data/a vector to help us help you?

Comment: @Nova That's right - the data aren't mixed together, but rather exist separately in different Elasticsearch backend systems.  The idea behind this function is that I can extract data from a regional database (either the EU or US one) and then apply a timezone offset to it to shift the data displayed in accordance to the desired timezone.  In a sense, it's creating an illusion as to the timezones displayed - it is correct, however.

Comment: Can you give us small dataframes to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I made an oversight in the order of assignment implementations and have just now spotted it.

For those who might be experiencing similar problems, it might be worth highlighting where I went wrong: I set the `offset` value after it was used, meaning that it was used/processed (using the previous iteration's value) and then it was assigned the new value.

In short, my implementation was completely correct but **the order of events was incorrect**.

Therefore, make sure that you set the required values before they are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work.

```
> time_function <- function(region){
+   # Function body
+   if (region == "EU") {
+     offset = "+00:00:00"
+     # Code to connect to EU ElasticSearch server
+   } else if (region == "US") {
+     offset = "-06:00:00"
+     # Code to connect to US ElasticSearch server
+   } else {
+     stop(paste0("Incorrect region supplied: ", region))
+   }
+   
+   return(offset)
+ }
> 
> time_function("EU")
[1] "+00:00:00"
> time_function("US")
[1] "-06:00:00"
> time_function("CH")
Error in time_function("CH") : Incorrect region supplied: CH
```

To optimize your code, you can use the switch.

```
> time_function <- function(region){
+   # Function body
+   offset <- switch(region,
+       EU = "+00:00:00",
+       US = "-06:00:00",
+       stop(paste0("Incorrect region supplied: ", region)))
+ 
+   return(offset)
+ }
> 
> time_function("EU")
[1] "+00:00:00"
> time_function("US")
[1] "-06:00:00"
> time_function("CH")
Error in time_function("CH") : Incorrect region supplied: CH
```

With two parameters:

```
> time_function <- function(region){
+   # Function body
+   list2env(switch(region,
+          EU = list(offset = "+00:00:00", con = "EU_con"),
+          US = list(offset = "+00:00:00", con = "US_con"),
+          stop(paste0("Incorrect region supplied: ", region))), envir = environment())
+   
+   return(c(offset, con))
+ }
> 
> time_function("EU")
[1] "+00:00:00" "EU_con"   
> time_function("US")
[1] "+00:00:00" "US_con"   
> time_function("CH")
Error in list2env(switch(region, EU = list(offset = "+00:00:00", con = "EU_con"),  : 
  Incorrect region supplied: CH
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but is it possible to perform more than one task based on what the condition is?  I need to not only set the `offset` value, but also connect to the corresponding Elasticsearch server.